# I have a form that collect data from a user that I need to stop with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have created a contact form using JavaScript which uses prompt to enter data into a variable. I then need to validate the data entered, and if it is not correct, I need the entire thing to stop there and ask for a valid entry. Unfortunately, I am using prompt to get 2 values from the user, and I cannot get the validation to do anything, or change anything. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  
    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title> Support Contact </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylez.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var email = document.getElementById("email");
    function checkEmail(email)
    {

        var reg1 = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if(reg1.test(email) == false) {
            alert("Please enter a valid Email address!!")} else
         if(reg1.test(email) == true) {
                }
    }

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var email;
    var name;
    email=prompt("Please enter your primary Email address....", "");

    name=prompt("Please enter your name.","");
    document.write("Thank you ", name, " someone will contact you within 48 hours!!"); 
    // --></script></head>
    <body><h1> Support Contact Page</h1><h2 align="center">
    <table width="200" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>Available m-sun</td>
    <td>Except Holidays</td>
    <td><div align="center">Email replies</div></td>
    </tr>
    </table></h2>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/300px-Basketball_pictogram.svg.png" width="103"
    height="101" alt="home" /></a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I need to stop everything if the Email entered is not valid, as per the if conditional statement. How can I stop it if the variable reg1 does not pass the test?

Comment: Because nobody uses the [museum](http://victoriaandalbert.london.museum/) TLD or has [a `+` in their email address](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/07/20/plus-sign-in-email-addresses/).

Answer (score 2):

In the test where you catch if it fails, return false.

```
if(reg1.test(email) == false) {
    alert("Please enter a valid Email address!!")
    return false;
} else
```